# Imprimir texto e imagem em impressora Zebra

Tags: java, android, impressora

Eu usei o "Zebra Designer" para gerar um "código" para a impressora Zebra interpretar, porém eu não sei como adicionar uma imagem no meio dessa impressão dinamicamente, tipo... eu tenho um tablet que o cliente pode assinar diretamente em sua tela, depois de feito um cadastro com algumas informações será impresso um formulário com os dados e a assinatura digital, o maior problema é como colocar essa imagem dinamicamente juntamente com o texto? Notei que ao colocar uma imagem qualquer no "Zebra Designer" ele gerar um tipo de array de byte (eu acho)... Segue meu string.xml com os dados...

**O que for ¶ será adicionado um texto dinamico e o que tiver X é um checklist...**

Cheguei a colocar isso para uma imagem, mas não sei seguir depois... 
 **PCX 0 0**

```
<string name="notificacao_ZP_01">! 0 200 200 2805 1</string>
<string name="notificacao_ZP_IMG">PCX 0 0</string>
<string name="notificacao_ZP_02">T 5 0 156 26 ¶</string><!-- Id notificação -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_03">T 5 0 170 59 ¶</string><!-- Ano -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_04">T 5 0 270 193 ¶</string><!-- Linha de transmissão -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_05">T 5 0 270 236 ¶</string><!-- Torres envolvidas -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_06">T 5 0 282 277 X</string><!-- Risco a operacionalidade - Alto -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_07">T 5 0 375 277 X</string><!-- Risco a operacionalidade - Médio -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_08">T 5 0 483 277 X</string><!-- Risco a operacionalidade - Baixo -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_09">T 5 0 583 277 X</string><!-- Risco a operacionalidade - Nenhum-->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_10">T 5 0 108 389 ¶</string><!-- Nome -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_11">T 5 0 126 477 ¶</string><!-- Endereço -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_12">T 5 0 511 520 ¶</string><!-- Telefone -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_13">T 5 0 103 563 ¶</string><!-- Bairro -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_14">T 5 0 132 607 ¶</string><!-- Municipio -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_15">T 5 0 208 653 ¶</string><!-- ponto de referência -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_16">T 5 0 300 687 X</string><!-- Estado civil - Solteiro -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_17">T 5 0 411 687 X</string><!-- Estado civil - Casado -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_18">T 5 0 538 687 X</string><!-- Estado civil - Viúvo -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_19">T 5 0 645 687 X</string><!-- Estado civil - Outros -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_20">T 5 0 322 743 ¶</string><!-- Quantas pessoas residem no local -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_21">T 5 0 321 784 ¶</string><!-- Quanto tempo no local -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_22">T 5 0 290 890 X</string><!-- Possui medidor - SIM -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_23">T 5 0 380 890 X</string><!-- Possui medidor - NÃO -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_24">T 5 0 290 980 X</string><!-- Apresentou conta de luz - SIM -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_25">T 5 0 380 980 X</string><!-- Apresentou conta de luz  - NÃO -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_26">T 5 0 236 940 ¶</string><!-- Numero medidor -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_27">T 5 0 646 940 ¶</string><!-- Ligado em -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_28">T 5 0 207 1028 ¶</string><!-- Numero cliente -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_29">T 5 0 178 1130 X</string><!-- Alvenaria -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_30">T 5 0 314 1149 X</string><!-- Madeira -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_31">T 5 0 440 1149 X</string><!-- Outros -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_texto_x_1">T 5 0 554 1149 X</string><!-- Outros Texto -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_32">T 5 0 178 1198 X</string><!-- Nova -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_33">T 5 0 314 1190 X</string><!-- Antiga -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_34">T 5 0 440 1198 X</string><!-- Em construção -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_35">T 5 0 178 1230 X</string><!-- Residência -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_36">T 5 0 314 1230 X</string><!-- Comércio -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_37">T 5 0 439 1230 X</string><!-- Esportes -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_38">T 5 0 575 1230 X</string><!-- Outros -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_texto_x_2">T 5 0 679 1237 X</string><!-- Outros Texto -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_39">T 5 0 178 1269 X</string><!-- Invasão -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_40">T 5 0 314 1269 X</string><!-- Alugado -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_41">T 5 0 438 1269 X</string><!-- Comprado -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_42">T 5 0 575 1269 X</string><!-- Posse -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_43">T 5 0 37 1375 ¶</string><!-- Observação 01-->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_44">T 5 0 270 1680 ¶</string><!-- Resp. pela fiscalização-->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_45">T 5 0 137 1733 ¶</string><!-- Matricula -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_46">T 5 0 618 1733 ¶</string><!-- Data -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_47">T 5 0 225 1795 ¶</string><!-- excluir --><!-- -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_48">T 5 0 38 2433 ¶</string><!-- Endereço -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_49">T 5 0 451 2488 ¶</string><!-- Id ocupação -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_50">T 5 0 654 2488 ¶</string><!-- Ano -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_53">T 0 0 45 2029 ¶</string><!-- Resp. Fiscalização -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_54">T 0 0 229 2029 ¶</string><!-- Matrícula -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_55">T 0 0 493 2029 ¶</string><!-- Data -->
<string name="notificacao_ZP_56">PRINT</string>
<string name="notificacao_ZP_BREAK_INICIAL">|</string>
<string name="notificacao_ZP_BREAK_FINAL">||</string>
```

Exemplo de um PRN que fiz na parte que seria a imagem (Resumido)...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, quando trabalhava com uma TLP2844, eu gerava toda a informação que queria no ZebraDesigner e, mandava imprimir em arquivo( arquivo.prn ). Alterava o conteudo e depois copiava para porta LTP1.
copy arquivo.prn > LPT1